# Virtualbox forward specific ip to guest

Tags: virtualbox

I have a dedicated server with `Ubuntu 13.10` installed and a basic installation with `Virtualbox` and `phpvirtualbox` to manage the guest OSs on it. I have two IP addresses pointing to the server and I would like to use one of them purely for a virtual OS I have with `Ubuntu 12.04` on it.

This means that every port etc. would pass through the host server and be forwarded straight on to this guest OS.

I have looked at the different network methods on VirtualBox but none seem to be for me.

If I use NAT and port forwarding I can set the guest PC to only register calls to those ports through that 2nd IP which is great. However I cant use any standard ports that already are in use on the host PC like SSH or 80 as the host PC uses them on both IPs

How can I get the host OS to just pass everything through to a specific guest OS for a specific IP?

Have I done this wrong and I need to use a different hosting type?

**EDIT:**

From research and comments it seems bridging should be the way forward but again i am stuck, here is my /etc/network/interfaces file..

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address   1.2.3.4
  broadcast 1.2.3.5
  netmask   255.255.255.200
  gateway   1.2.3.1
  # default route to access subnet
  up route add -net 1.2.3.6 netmask 255.255.255.220 gw 1.2.3.1 eth0

iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f8:161:9442::2
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1

  #create bridge using additional IP
  auto br1
    iface br1 inet static
    address 2.3.4.5
    netmask 255.255.255.220
    gateway 2.3.4.1
    broadcast 2.3.4.7
    bridge_ports br1 vbox0 vbox1
```

The server is a Hetzner EX with an additional IP thats on the same MAC address (i can get a different MAC from them if needs be?)

With the above settings i set my Win7 guest OS to be bridged to br1 and set the ip in windows to be static with the same settings i.e.

```
address 2.3.4.5
netmask 255.255.255.220
gateway 2.3.4.1
```

But it couldnt pick up a network

Lastly i have added to /etc/vbox/interfaces:

```
vbox0 vbox br1
vbox1 vbox br1
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/569213/virtualbox-forward-specific-ip-to-guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a LOT of trial and error, this seems to be the most reliable option...

http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Netzkonfiguration_Debian/en#Bridged

> Bridged With a bridged configuration, packets are sent directly. The
>   guest system behaves as if independent. As this makes the MAC
>   addresses of the guest system visible from the outside, a virtual MAC
>   address needs to be requested via the Hetzner Robot and assigned to
>   the guest network card. The bridge gets the same network configuration
>   as eth0. The configuration of eth0 is omitted without replacement.

Get seperate MAC addresses for each of the additional IPs

Then use this for the hosts /etc/network/interfaces..

```
# remove or disable configuration for eth0
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet static
#
auto  br0
iface br0 inet static
 address (Main IP)
 netmask (like eth0, e.g: 255.255.255.254)
 gateway (same as that for the main IP)
 bridge_ports eth0
 bridge_stp off
 bridge_fd 1
 bridge_hello 2
 bridge_maxage 12
```

Set up the Guest OS in virtualbox to use a bridged network and select br0, then in advanced settings set the mac of the network adapter to the MAC address that Hetzner gave you for the new IP (without any :)

Then in the Guest OS use this..

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet static
address (ADD IP 1)
broadcast (FOR ADD IP 1)
netmask (FOR ADD IP 1)
gateway (MAIN IP)
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the IP address from the host then assign the very same address to the guest on a [bridged interface](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged).

Comment: Is my setup correct (added above) for a bridged interface though? If i add a win7 guest os and then attach that to br1, then set the ip address manually to "2.3.4.5" etc then it says IP address conflict??

Comment: There is nothing to configure on the Linux networking side. Everything is handled by VirtualBox. (answer updated with a link to the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instructions with little initial success - br0 wouldn't come up on my Hetzner box.

I found the solution was:

```
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
brctl addbr br0
```

You may also need to remove the default entry in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent.net.rules` ,

Of course you should see what Mac address has been allocated to you by Hetzner (in the Robot) and then:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <VMName> --macaddress1 xxxxxxxxxx
```